# Mail sending is failure in php contact us form

Tags: php, html, email

I am creating a `contact us` form, In that i am using HTML and PHP .Now my doubt is after click the submit button the details are not sending to mail,I want to know where i am mistaken on my code.
 Here my `HTML` code for create the form

```
<form action="sendmail.php" method="post" >
   <table width="100%" border="0"align="center"cellpadding="3"cellspacing="1">
      <tr>
         <td width="10%">Subject</td>
         <td width="2%">: </td>
         <td width="82%"><input name="name" type="text" id="name" size="50"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>Detail</td>
         <td width="2%">: </td>
         <td width="82%"><textarea name="detail" cols="50" rows="4"id="detail"></textarea></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>Email</td>
         <td>: </td>
         <td><input name="customer_mail" type="text" id="customer_mail" size="50"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>Name</td>
         <td>: </td>
         <td><input name="name" type="text" id="name" size="50"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td><input type="submit" name="send" value="Submit">
            <input type="reset" name="submit" value="Reset">
         </td>
      </tr>
   </table>
</form>
```

`PHP` code is below:

```
<?php 
  $subject="$subject";
  $message="$detail";
    $mail_from="customer_mail";
//From
$header="from: $name <$mail_from>";
//Enter your email address
$to="simon@abcinfomedia.in";
$sendmail=mail($to,$subject,$message,$header);
//check mail send to ur mail
if($sendmail){
    echo"success";
}
else{
    echo"Error";
}
?>
```

Comment: is there any output for this code?

Comment: @kejsu ,PHP code is printed that i am posting above ...that is output i am getting

Comment: $_POST['name'] ......get value like this and the assign to mail variable .

Comment: Not that this will solve the problem... but you have two `input`s with the same `name` attribute: "name"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not working because you're not filling the variables with the data from the form by using $_POST[''].

The HTML doesn't change, but try this PHP:

```
<?php
$subject   = $_POST['subject'];
$message   = $_POST['detail'];
$mail_from = $_POST['customer_mail'];
$header    = "from: $name <$mail_from>";
$to        = "simon@abcinfomedia.in";

//check mail send to ur mail
if(mail($to,$subject,$message,$header)){
    echo"success";
}
else{
    echo"Error";
}
?>
```

I have defined subject, message and mail_from using the $_POST data from the form. For the if statement, I have dropped the part where you store the mail() function as a variable and just put it straight into the if.

This will simultaneously send the email and check it at the same time.

In my test, the email worked but there were flaws because some of your fields are missing and not defined, but I believe the above solves your initial problem. :)

Comment: First of all, where are the variables $subject and $detail defined?

Comment: ok let me try that

Answer (score 1):

please try this:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['send']) && !empty($_POST['send'])) {
$subject = $_POST['subject'];//if you sent by post method else put manually
$message = $_POST['detail'];
$mail_from = $_POST['customer_mail'];
$header = "from: $name <$mail_from>";
//Enter your email address
$to = "simon@abcinfomedia.in";
$sendmail = mail($to, $subject, $message, $header);
//check mail send to ur mail
if ($sendmail) {
    echo "success";
} else {
    echo "Error";
}
}

?>
```

Comment: ok let me try and reply you